# How to cancel filter if they are no results

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I’m having a lot of trouble with something that I thought it will be easy. I have 200-300 lines of data. My header is on row 7.I need to filter (column D)with one criteria . If it turns results I need to copy all the lines in a new worksheet without the header. If they are no results then I need to cancel the filter!

I tried pretty much everything I could find on other posts but nothing works! If I try to use if statement, keeps jumping from else to end sub!

Please, some help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Add your code to the question, otherwise you're unlikely to get an answer that solves your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.